# Updating data bound in @Directive's template selector from @Component Angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript, data-binding, angular2-directives, angular2-components

I was looking around a particular thing in Angular 2 where I need to update the directive's selector's data bound variable with the upcoming changes. It, however doesn't get updated on every change.

@Directive selector inside @Component's template, let's call **comp.html**

```
<sunburst-chart [className]="'sunburst-chart'" width="200" height="200" bind-data="costData">
    </sunburst-chart>
```

The data I am targeting is '**costData**'

Here is how the directive looks like,

```js
import { Directive, ElementRef, Attribute, SimpleChange, Input, OnChanges, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import * as d3 from 'd3';

@Directive({
    selector: 'sunburst-chart'
})
export class SunburstChart {}
```

```js
import {Component, OnInit, ViewEncapsulation} from '@angular/core';
import {AWSTotalCostService} from '../services/index';
import {Router} from '@angular/router';
import {CostPricingTileModel} from '../models/costpricingtile.model';


@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'costing-module-tile',
  templateUrl: 'costpricingtile.html',
  providers: [AWSTotalCostService],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
  styleUrls: ['costpricingtile.scss'],
})
export class CostPricingTileComponent implements OnInit {
  private costData : any;
```

This calls a service, that returns the data, after which, the view is not getting updated.

```js
private sample () : any {
    this.sampleService.sampleFun()
        .subscribe(
            data => {

            this.costData = data

        },
            error =>  this.errorMessage = error
    );
  }

  ngOnInit () : void {
   console.log('');
    this.sample();
  }
```

Any help is much appreciated.

The problem I am facing is, I am not able to update the changes to the bound data in the html.

PS. Using latest version of Angular ( The stable release, not beta versions )

Adding simpler terms,

Let's talk simple. I have a d3 chart that I 've created as a directive (@Directive) with selector 'sunburst-chart'. I have a component (@Component) that includes a templateUrl 'a html file', that has this selector as an element. I am pointing the data of that element to the component's data variable 'say costData'. Initially it works fine as I have some data present, when the costData gets changed from service, the costData gets updated, but the changes are not bound back to the selector. Hence the view change doesn't happen

Comment: It's not totally clear exactly what you're trying to do. Can explain a bit what the `bind-data` is actually used for? I could tell you to try to use `[bind-data]="costData"`. But I'm not sure, as I have no idea what is it you're actually trying to do

Comment: Let's talk simple.
I have a d3 chart that I 've created as a directive (@Directive) with selector 'sunburst-chart'.

I have a component (@Component) that includes a templateUrl 'a html file', that has this selector as an element.

I am pointing the data of that element to the component's data variable 'say costData'.

Initially it works fine as I have some data present, when the costData gets changed from service, the costData gets updated, but the changes are not bound back to the selector.

Hence the view change doesn't happen

Comment: @ArunKumar You say the initial data works fine, but new data doesn't update the directive right? Please tell us how the data is changed. For instance, the `sample()` function you showed sets the initial data in `ngOnInit` but we don't see how you update it later

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned that you're using the latest `Angular`.

Providers are no longer specified within the `@Component` decorator. Instead, you ought to move them to [`@NgModule`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/ngmodule.html)

There are three [types of directives](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/attribute-directives.html) in `Angular` and yours doesn't seem to fit any one of them.

- A component: directive with a template. Selector is an html tag such as your `sunburst-chart`, but it must use `@Component` decorator
- An attribute directive. Selector is an html attribute; eg: `[sunburst-chart]`
- A structural directive, such as `*ngIf`, to change the structure of the DOM

If you expect the selector to be an HTML tag, use a component instead of a directive.

Comment: It is said, it is optional to move providers. Only directives have to be moved outside. I am able to hit the service and get the response.

Comment: It works fine for the mock json. Only for the service it seems to be the problem